# Generating default gpg.conf with default gnupg2 utils

Tags: configuration, gpg

Is there a way to generate the default gpg.conf file?  I can't find one in my fs with `find / -name gpg.conf`.  I also tried checking `gpgconf` to see if it had an option for generating one, and looked for other gpg utils that come with the standard gnupg2 installation, but nothing stood out.

Comment: Define what you mean by "default" here. System-wide, per-user (including or excluding when creating new users), or only for your login? Have you checked the [GPG Documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/index.html) (for GPG itself, not gpgconf, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the contents of gpg.conf are only used to set options that are *not* the default. So if you want the default options, there's no reason to have a gpg.conf file.

That said, the correct placement for gpg.conf is in the `.gnupg` folder and it is easily created with `touch ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`.